# Room returning blank object

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, mediatorlivedata

I'm posting my room query result using the below code

```
_data.postValue(databaseImpl.findRepoById(id).value)
```

But it seems the returned object is empty. I'm guessing we need to observe databaseImpl.findRepoById(id), not access it directly but since it's in a viewmodel I don't have a lifecycleOwner to assign to the room query livedata.

```
       databaseImpl.observe(this, Observer { //!!this is modelview and not activity
            _data.postValue()
        })
```

What is the right way to use Room query and update a mediator live data?

Answer (score 0):

You could try use coroutines to query your data so you can have something like this for your DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users") 
fun findRepoById(id): Flow<User>
```

In your DatabaseImpl class return have it as:

```
 fun findRepoById(id): Flow<User>  = userDao.findRepoById(id)
```

Then in your ViewModel you could do this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
   databaseImpl.findRepoById(id).map { _data.postValue(it) }
}
```

Have a look at this article [Room and Coroutines](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5) by Florina Muntenescu
on how you could set up coroutines and use it with room.